# A child class should maintain a collection, how to bind its scope to a parent's class method?

Tags: java, architecture

I have two classes that share the same flow: I need to get info from the DB, process it and update it on a nosql DB.

The difference is very small: in one case I am sure I will get only one entity for each nosql record, so I can just process them, store them temporarily in a list and then get all the items in the list after the entities were processed.

In the second case I can have more than one entity for each index record. In this case I have to retrieve the current processed data, merge, and store again. After every entity was processed I am able to get the map.values() so I can update to the nosql.

As seen the difference is only on how the items are processed and how the data structure is temporarily stored.

My parent class has something like this:

```
public void run()
{
    process();
    sendToNosql(getProcessed())
}

protected abstract void process();
protected abstract List<Stuff> getProcessed();
```

The simple children is something like this:

```
List<Stuff> myStuff = new ArrayList<>();
@Override
protected void process()
{
    for(Entity e : loadFromDB()){
        myStuff.add(process(e));
    }
}

@Override
protected List<Stuff> getProcessed(){
    return myStuff;
}
```

And the complex one:

```
Map<int, Stuff> myStuff = new HashMap<>();
@Override
protected void process()
{
    for(Entity e : loadFromDB()){
        myStuff.put(e.getId(), process(e));
    }
}

@Override
protected List<Stuff> getProcessed(){
    return myStuff.values();
}
```

Because everything will be processed and the results will be used later, myStuff is an object attribute. This works fine.
But because these are stateless beans, I am only safe while I am in the run() method, if any other method is called, the myStuff attribute is not reliable.

I would like to avoid this risk, so I would like to have the run() method as myStuff attribute scope. How can I improve my architecture to achieve this while abstracting the underlying data structure? 
Or is this problem telling me I made something very wrong?

Comment: A single record is still a list of one. Is not possible to just expect a collection even when you know it ill process a single record?

Comment: It would be possible to make every child use a Map, but that seems strange because most of the cases are the simple one, so many classes will use a map (when a simpler structure could be used) because one class (the complex one) needs it. What you proposed is a possible solution, but I would be happier if each class could define its own temporary storage independently.

Comment: I see, but you must first answer one thing: Maintenances (thing in  a change on your data||entity) Ill need a change in both classes? If it ill require maintenaces in both classes it make changes to encapsulate all in a more generic one. Also if the complex case is the more unusual you can  consider doing the inverse: wrap it in one class ill call the single one many times

Comment: They apply to different entities in the database. Changes in an entity may cause changes in the class (on the method that parses from Entity to Stuff). Changes in the business process may impact the whole import flow. Sorry, I am not sure I get what you mean by "wrap it in one class ill call the single one many times"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For information in case anyone finds this question:
I used the [State pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern), so the child class generates a state when the process method starts. The state hides the way the information is stored (hash or list).